# Vuetify data table: shorten text based on column width

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

My Vuetify application uses the `v-data-table` component to display information like object descriptions, which can sometimes get quite long:

[image]

I'd like to shorten the displayed description text based on the actual width of the description column. Something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to get the actual displayed width of a `v-data-table` column (in pixels or in ems) in order to implement such a dynamic string shortening?

Comment: Could use CSS (truncate) and limit the length of the chars with some `splice`.